# ¿Se puede dar una recompensa a una respuesta wiki de comunidad?

Tags: soporte

En esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90648/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-exactamente-nth-child) autorrespondida se ha ofrecido una recompensa. La respuesta la convertí en wiki para que cualquiera la pueda mejorar o añadir algo que crea que falte.

Supongamos que el OP quisiera otorgar la recompensa a esa respuesta o que llegara el plazo y no hubiese ninguna respuesta más. ¿Qué ocurre con esos puntos? ¿Se pueden otorgar a una pregunta wiki? ¿Si no es posible y no hay más respuestas, vuelven los puntos al OP o que pasa?

Comment: Arrg! Es verdad ¿Cómo no la he visto? Antes de preguntar he buscado preguntas con la palabra recompensa y no he visto esa pregunta :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los puntos cuando realizas una recompensa, **NUNCA** vuelven al usuario que ha realizado la recompensa. En el peor de los casos, la recompensa se pierde.

Aclarado esto, hay una [muy buena respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) en meta.stackexchange.com aclarando tus dudas:

> **How does Community Wiki mode affect bounties?**
>
> Bounties are not affected by community wiki mode. When you award a bounty to an answer marked community wiki, the reputation bonus will be awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer.

O lo que es lo mismo:

> **¿Cómo afecta una Wiki de Comunidad a las bounties?**
>
> Las recompensas no son afectadas por el modo wiki de comunidad. Cuando otorgas una recompensa a una respuesta marcada como wiki de comunidad, el bono de reputación será otorgado al usuario que ha creado la revisión original de la respuesta.